# If LogManager.shutdown() is not invoked, is it possible JVM does not terminate?

Tags: java, exception, jvm, log4j

I thought that throwing exceptions from main() would definitely cause JVM to terminate, but I encountered a scenario where my Java application process did not terminate after an exception got thrown from main().

I'm still trying to figure out why JVM did not abort. Then I noticed that my code uses log4j but does not explicitly call LogManager.shutdown().

So, is it possible that, if LogManager.shutdown() is not invoked, JVM might not exit even when an exception is thrown from main()?

Comment: It is hard to say what your code is doing if you are not showing it. For example, it is possible to register an exception handler for thread groups, and that could be catching such things. Long story short: no code, thus no good chance of a real answer ...

Comment: After your app throws an exception, use jstack to list all non-daemon threads. An app exits when it is explicitly shut down, or when all non-daemon threads terminate.

Comment: No. I never call it.

Comment: When your `main`method and hence your main thread terminates — whether normally or abnormally — the JVM will continue to run as long as there are other non-daemon threads running. I don’t know whether Log4j may keep a non-daemon thread alive until explicitly shut down.